# Why is supportsAlternateIcons set to false by default for iOS 14/15/16 builds?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm adding alternate app icons to my project. In iOS 13, it's working perfectly, but in later versions it is not.

`UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons` is set to false by default for iOS 14, 15, and 16.

I tried with the same code but in a different fresh application and it works there for every iOS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: Build on intel chip mac. I built on M1 mac, Xcode 13 hence this feature was not working and the value was set to false by default. Running the same project on intel chip Mac works fine.